# How to create a Excel VBA that uses vlookup variables

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

[Search the given cell values in a worksheet to find corresponding info another workbook and returning it the original workbook in the corresponding first empty column]

```
Sub Macro1()   

Dim filename As String
Dim myFileName As Workbook
Dim mySheetName As Worksheet
Dim myRangeName As Range

'get workbook path
filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Please select a file")

'set our workbook and open it
Set myFileName = Application.Workbooks.Open(filename)

'set our worksheet
Set mySheetName = myFileName.Worksheets("Table 1")

'set the range for vlookup all active rows and columns
Set myRangeName = mySheetName.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

'return to the original Workbook
ThisWorkbook.Activate


Dim LookUp As String
Dim returnValue As Variant
Dim OriginalCell As String
Dim UpdatedCell As String
Dim FirstRow As String

Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Cells

lastRow = Rng.Find(what:="*", after:=Rng.Cells(1), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

WhatToFind = Chr(10)

'Finds all the rows with sequnce numbers then deletes everything in the specified cell after the first line break

For i = 1 To lastRow

    FindRow = Range("A:A").Find(what:=i, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row

    If FindRow >= 1 Then
        OriginalCell = Cells(FindRow, "B").Value
        UpdatedCell = Left(OriginalCell, InStr(OriginalCell, WhatToFind) - 1)
        Cells(FindRow, "B").Value = UpdatedCell

        ' Uses the new cleaned up specified cell and searches another workbook,
        ' which the user selects and the first work sheet within that workbook and returns
        ' the corresponding info back to the original workbook in a the the next empty column. 

        LookUp = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(FindRow, 2), myRangeName, 1, False)

        Cells(i, "I").Value = LookUp
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

[image: The first image is of the workbook containing the macro]

[image: the second is the workbook from which it extracts info from]

Comment: The Vlookup is where the error occurs.

Comment: Please at least tell us which error -.-

Comment: What if you hardcode the vlookup? So instead of using variables to build the string, hardcode it and see if that makes it work. Sometimes a variable is not what you think it is.

Comment: @Ulli I think he means the fifth row from the bottom, starting with `LookUp=`

Comment: @UlliSchmid it says compile error "Expected: list separator or )"

Comment: and @Andreas it worked when I had a direct address for lookup.

Comment: @Alex :ThumbsUp:. Always expect a variable to be wrong when something does not work :-)

Comment: @Alex can you upload a screen-shot of your sheet ? will be easier to debug ans help you

Comment: @Alex see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you have the ***VLookup*** line set up like this:

```
LookUp = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLOOKUP(Cells(i, 2),"[" & myFileName & "]" & mySheetName & "!" & myRangeName & ",1,False)
```

You alreay did 95% of the work defining the `Range`, you can use the ***VLookup*** line (and the previous line) like this:

```
    'set the range for vlookup all active rows and columns
    Set myRangeName = mySheetName.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    ' Uses the new cleaned up specified cell and searches another workbook which the user selects and the first worksheet
    ' within that workbook and returns the corresponding info back to the original workbook in a cell next to the empty column.
    LookUp = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 2), myRangeName, 1, False)
```

**Edit 1:** added the code to support the additional request by PO.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim filename                As String
Dim myFileName              As Workbook
Dim currentSheet            As Worksheet
Dim mySheetName             As Worksheet
Dim myRangeName             As Range
Dim lastRow                 As Long
Dim i                       As Long
Dim matchRow                As Long


'set current worksheet
Set currentSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table 1")

'get workbook path
filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Please select a file")

'set our workbook and open it
Set myFileName = Application.Workbooks.Open(filename)

'set searched worksheet
Set mySheetName = myFileName.Worksheets("Table 1")

' find last row in Column A ("Item No.")
lastRow = mySheetName.Cells(mySheetName.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'set the range for Vlookup all active rows and columns
Set myRangeName = mySheetName.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)

' find last row in Column B in This Workbook ("Item No.")
lastRow = currentSheet.Cells(currentSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
    With currentSheet
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(i, "B"), myRangeName, 0)) Then
            matchRow = Application.Match(.Cells(i, "B"), myRangeName, 0)
            .Cells(i, "J") = mySheetName.Cells(matchRow, "J").Value
            .Cells(i, "K") = mySheetName.Cells(matchRow, "Q").Value
        Else ' Item No. record not found
            ' put #NA in cells, to know it's not found
            .Cells(i, "J") = CVErr(xlErrNA)
            .Cells(i, "K") = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        End If

    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks that cleared up my syntax error but its not returning anything back to original workbook in the desired open cell. I uploaded two images of the workbook containing the macro (image 1) and the one to extract info from (image 2). when I check the code after I run it shows that LookUp is highlighted yellow and contains nothing. also I updated the arrangement of the code a little and added a few things trying to fix the error.

Comment: @Alex in your original post you asked to resolve the error you get in Vlookup, now you are asking to debug your code. What is the purpose of your code ? to search for what value in which column ?

Comment: to match the item number in column B in the original workbook to the Item number in Column A in the second workbook and return it to the corresponding cell in the original workbook.

Comment: @Alex help me understand your needs a little better. _Item No._ in column B, is from the upper image ? what is the name of that workbook and worksheet. Is Column A in the lower image ? what is the name of the workbook and worksheet ? Where do you want the result ? which sheet and Column ?

Comment: item no. in column B is from upper image the workbook is "finalscope" and the worksheet is "Table 1". Column A is from the lower image, the workbook is called "2016.08.05" worksheet is also "Table 1". I want it to match the item numbers and return the Unit and Price (In the bottom image) in separate columns on the same row as the corresponding item number on the upper image in the next blank columns on "Table 1" in columns j and K.

Comment: @Alex what columns are **Unit** and **Price** in the lower image ? ("2016.08.05" workbook)

Comment: They are J and Q respectively.

Comment: Thanks it didn't work as expected everything came back #NA but I implemented some of your code into my own and it works for the most part but got me over a major barrier. I'm currently trying to find out why it stops on certain items when searching between the two workbooks even though there is an exact match. The error message "Unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class". Thanks again though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error - change

```
& myRangeName & ",1,False)
```

to

```
& myRangeName ,1,False)
```

Comment: Thanks that helped.